# Perform conditional map join

Tags: javascript

I have to join an array of javascript object property, but to add the property value to the string I have to check if another property is not `undefined` or  `false`:

What I do now:

```
var out = [];
$scope.grid.dataSource.data().map(function (user) {
  if (angular.isDefined(user.Selected) && user.Selected == true)
    out.push(user.UserPersonID);
});

var ids = out.join(",");
```

I'd like do something like this:

```
var ids = $scope.grid.dataSource.data().map(function (user) { if (user.Selected) return user.UserPersonID; }).join(",");
```

But if the `user.Selected` is not true I'll obtain a long list of `,` ('123,,,234,,,').

How can I get the same result without using the `out` array?

Comment: Use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var out = $scope.grid.dataSource.data().filter(function(user) {
    return angular.isDefined(user.Selected) && user.Selected;
}).map(function (user) {
    return user.UserPersonID;
});
```